# Open Saml v4 assertion.setsignature missing

Tags: opensaml

It seems in open saml v4 the Assertion does not have setsignature or getsignature methods.

In open saml v4 how to sign assertion and how to get signature of assertion and validate it?

I am using ResponseBuilder, IssuerBuilder, AasertionBuilder to build the saml response